# Accessing private URL from GitHub actions

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, github-actions, aws-vpn

On AWS we have an EKS and VPC Endpoint. Inside EKS we have deployed unpub server (https://pub.dev/packages/unpub) and we are accessing it over AWS VPN using this url http://unpub.internal.abc . For AWS VPN we are using SSO based authentication. All working fine but there is a requirement that github actions can access this internal URL of unpub because our repos need unpub during build process.

Any idea how can we access internal URLs in GitHub actions? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you have to either expose your endpoint to the internet or deploy the "GitHub action runners" inside your network.

A self-hosted runner is a system that you can deploy and manage to execute jobs from GitHub Actions on GitHub.com. Once self hosted runners are configured inside your network, it will have access to the private endpoints.
More on self hosted runner: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners

Comment: Not really true, there are MANY ways in between, e.g. port forwarding via SSH, the Session manager (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html), ...

Comment: @luk2302 can you please explain a bit? Thanks

Comment: You can create Github runner fleet in your network(https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners). These runners basically polls the Github and executes in your network hence you have access to all internal endpoints.